# Android Matrix setValues() Row Major Or Column Major

Tags: android, matrix, graphics

I am using android.graphics.Matrix in my project. I want to set the values in the Matrix, so I will use the setValues(float [] values) function for this. My doubt is whether the float [] values parameter is row major or column major. In other words is the values array like:

```
    values = {m[0][0], m[0][1], m[0][2], m[1][0], m[1][1], m[1][2], m[2][0], m[2][1], m[2][2]};
```

Or

```
    values = {m[0][0], m[1][0], m[2][0], m[0][1], m[1][1], m[2][1], m[0][2], m[1][2], m[2][2]};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking the result of `Matrix.setTranslate(0, 12)` reveals the following sequence: `1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 12.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0`

Wether to call this layout row major or column major depends on your view of the vectors you are going to transform.

Imagining them to be column vectors and thus post multiplied you will have the scenario below:

```
  | 1   0   0 |     x
  | 0   1  12 |  x  y
  | 0   0   1 |     1
```

Thinking of them as row vectors you will get the opposite impression like in the following scenario:

```
              | 1   0  0 |
  (x y 1)  x  | 0   1  0 |
              | 0  12  1 |
```

You should be able to find the "right" version and assign your m[i][j], or was it m[j][i] (?) accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

They are row major, post-wise.

(i.e. the first 3 values correspond to the first row, the next 3 values correspond to the 2nd row, and the last 3 values correspond to the last row - assuming you are using post operations, i.e. that

> M' = T * M,

where T is the transformation matrix, and M is the original matrix.)

This is indeed important if you are receiving values from a column major matrix, as it can change the results drastically.

There's no transpose method on Matrix, but you can use this code:

```
  public static void transpose(float[]m, float[] result) {
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
        for (int j=0;j<3;j++)
           result[j*3+i] = m[i*3+j];
  }
```